# lazy loaded NHibernate collections into ViewModels?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, collections, mvvm

I have my NHibernate mappings set to lazy loading = true.
In my CustomersViewModel I have something like:

```
        foreach (Customer c in _customerRepository)
        {
            this.Customers.Add(new SingleCustomerViewModel(c));
        }
```

This obviously kills all the lazy loading, since the customers are passed one by one.

How do I get my collections (including subcollections and sub-subcollections a.s.f.) of model-objects into the corresponding ObservableCollections of my ViewModels to bind to the UI?

This seems to be a common problem, but I found no answer, neither here nor on the Googles ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure I completely understand  the question . 
But I was thinking why not change your getCustomers method to

```
 IEnumerable<SingleCustomerViewModel> getCustomers(){
     return  from c in _customerRepository select SingleCustomerViewModel(c);
  }
```

Since LINQ expressions are lazily evaluated you nhibernate collection wont be initialized until its actually bound to the UI .

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic "SELECT N+1" problem: whichever query layer you are using for NHibernate offers you a way to eagerly load the child collections in your initial query to avoid this row-by-row query pattern.

With the LINQ provider, for example:

```
session.Query<Customer> ()
        .FetchMany (c => c.Widgets) // eagerly load child collections
        .ThenFetchMany (w => w.Frobbers); // now get grandchild collection
```

If you're using HQL, just add the `fetch` keyword to your joins.